# How do I not display the required input on a list?

Tags: python

here is my code:

```
incorrect_names = []

name = "John"
while True:
    name = input("Enter your name:")
    incorrect_names.append(name)
    print(incorrect_names)
    
    if name == "John":
        print("user enters John")
        break
```

Only input that does not match the criteria is supposed to be in a list. In this case, only names other than John should be in a list. But in my code when I input John it displays the name in a list as well.

Comment: Use an `if` statement before appending to the list.

Answer (score 1):

The `if` statement needs to be before you append to the list.

```
while True:
    name = input("Enter your name:")
    if name == "John":
        print("user enters John")
        break
    incorrect_names.append(name)

print(incorrect_names)
```